# regexp automatically runs on function input?

Tags: python, regex, function

So, I've searched for a while and couldn't find anything, so I've decided to turn to the experts on SO to help me clarify what is going on.

I am learning Python and whilst learning about regular expressions, I've come across an interesting bit of syntax that I can't quite figure out. In this example, a function is defined which runs a regular expression on the input parameter, returning the match of the integer as a float, or throwing an exception if the input doesn't match something that looks like a number:

```
import re
def getNumber(token):
  r'-?[1-9][0-9]*.?[0-9]*'
  return float(token)
```

this function can be called like so:

```
print getNumber('123.123')
print getNumber('123.123')+40
```

which would output:

```
123.123
163.123
```

I am trying to understand the mechanics of how this is happening. I understand that we are declaring a regular expression object with the call to r'STRING', but somehow just declaring that regular expression causes the token parameter to get passed into the expression as well. Is this a trait with functions explicitly containing a parameter called "token"? Is there a behavior associated with multiple parameters? It definitely seems that some work has been done here to provide a pythonic syntax, I would just like to know the details of how it works and how to use it in the future. Pointing me to documentation would be great, as I couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: This is not the way to create regex object. Please take a look at [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#examples).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function isn't running a regular expression on the input ... It's calling `float` on the input which is converting the input to a floating point number.  The "regular expression" that is there is nothing more than a docstring on the function.

Note that `r"this is a string"` simply creates a "raw string" which has nothing to do with regex (`"\t"` is tab whereas `r"\t"` is the literal characters `'\'` and `'t'`) .

Comment: And as far as docstrings go, this is one of the least enlightening ones I have ever come across.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I really appreciate the clarification, especially on such a n00b question

Comment: @HansThen -- Agreed.  Whoever wrote that function should have just used put the entirety of the source-code (sans docstring to avoid recurion) into the docstring.  Or, maybe they should have just written `getNumber = float` ... then the docstring would actually be useful ;^)